# Is there a way to return a calculated value from a nested query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Ok I've spent a week trying to figure this out but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. There are two similar problems that, I think, are easier to explain after seeing the pseudo(ish) code. Here is the first one

```
SELECT P_CODE, P_DESCRIPT, @diff
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE @diff :=
    (SELECT ROUND(ABS(P_PRICE -(SUM(P_PRICE)/COUNT(P_PRICE))),2)
    FROM PRODUCT
    WHERE P_PRICE in
        (SELECT P_PRICE
        FROM PRODUCT));
```

Basically, I have product table where I'm trying to return the primary key, description, and difference between the product's price and the average price for all entries. In a similar note here is the second problem

```
SELECT *, @val
FROM LINE
WHERE P_CODE in 
    (SELECT P_CODE
    FROM LINE
    HAVING COUNT(P_CODE) >
    (@val = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LINE)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P_CODE)
    FROM LINE)));
```

Here I'm trying to return all fields from the line table (which is basically a receipt table) for which the product for that entry has more items sold than the average number sold

Is it clear what I'm trying to do with these? I'm trying to return other values as well as a calculated value that I can only calculate using values from another table (in list form if that wasn't clear). I'm not too sure but perhaps JOIN statements might work here? I'm new to mysql and haven't quite understood how to best employ JOIN statements yet. If someone could show me how to approach problems like these or at least point me to a link that describes how to do this (as I've had no luck finding one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a subquery that returns the average price:

```
SELECT p.p_code, p.p_descript, ROUND(ABS(p.p_price - x.avg_price)) AS price_diff
FROM product AS p
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(p_price) AS avg_price
    FROM product
) AS x
```

Notice that there's a built-in `AVG()` function, you don't need to use `SUM()` and `COUNT()`. Also, there's no point to `WHERE p_price in (SELECT p_price FROM product)` -- that test is obviously always true.

```
SELECT l.*
FROM line AS l
JOIN (
    SELECT p_code, COUNT(*) AS code_count
    FROM line
    GROUP BY p_code
) AS l1 ON l.p_code = l1.p_code
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT p_code) AS avg_count
    FROM line
) AS x ON l1.code_count > x.avg_count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I thought I needed to use joins (though we never went over cross joins). I'm aware there is an AVG function, I probably kept it that way because I actually wrote the second one first and needed the distinct P_CODE there and just copied and pasted

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I have product table where I'm trying to return the primary key, description, and difference between the product's price and the average price for all entries

Using MySQL's user variables makes the queries a bit harder.

There are many methods to get what you need.

**Method one**

Using a inner select or a subquery

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT.P_CODE
    , PRODUCT.P_DESCRIPT
    , ROUND(ABS((PRODUCT.P_PRICE) - (SELECT AVG(PRODUCT_INNER.P_PRICE) FROM PRODUCT AS PRODUCT_INNER)), 2) AS diff
FROM 
    PRODUCT
```

**Method two**

Using a CROSS JOIN

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT.P_CODE
    , PRODUCT.P_DESCRIPT
    , ROUND(ABS(PRODUCT.P_PRICE - product_avg.avg_product_price), 2) AS diff
FROM 
    PRODUCT
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         AVG(PRODUCT.P_PRICE) AS avg_product_price
     FROM 
         PRODUCT) AS product_avg
```